# Creating blog on Django - URLs won't cooperate

Tags: python, django, web

System information: Using Sublime Text 3.1.1 and Mac 10.14 Mojave and Django Version    2.1.3

I am creating a blog in Django for Python. It has a homepage and then a 'posts' page that when you click on it lists the titles of the posts that have been created. When I click on a title of a post, it should bring me to a page that has the title and then the text of the post underneath it. However, this is where my project stops working. I get the error on my web browser:

```
TypeError at /posts/1/
post() got an unexpected keyword argument 'post_id'
Request Method: GET
```

I am trying to use a number for the url that correstponds to the blog post. So one blog post would be at http://localhost:8000/posts/1/, the next at http://localhost:8000/posts/2/, etc. Let me show you how I am trying to do this.

In my urls.py I create the following path in the 'urlpatterns' list:
`path('posts/<int:post_id>/',views.post,name='post')`. From what I understand, this should store an integer value as 'post_id'.

My view, in 'views.py', for a post looks like:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import BlogPost as Post
def post(request):
  """Show the text of a single blog post"""
  post=Post.objects.get(id=post_id)
  context = {'post':post}
  return render(request,'blogs/post.html',context)
```

For reference, my 'models.py' looks like: (with the appropriate things imported, of course)

```
class BlogPost(models.Model):
    """A blog post"""
    title=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text=models.TextField()
    date_added=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    def __str__(self):
        """Return a string representation of the model"""
        return self.text
```

My template for a post stems from a very basic 'base.html' and looks like:

```
{% extends 'blogs/base.html' %}
{% block content %}
    <p>{{ post.title }}</p> 
    <p>{{ post.text }}</p>  
{% endblock content %}
</pre>
```

This template is also linked to my template 'posts.html':

```
{% extends "blogs/base.html" %}

{% block content %}

  <p>Posts</p>
  <ul>
    {% for post in posts %} 
      <li>
        <a href="{% url 'blogs:post' post.id %}">{{ post.title }}</a>
      </li> 
    {% empty %}
      <li>No posts have been submitted yet</li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>

{% endblock content %}
```

The most important line being the one with "post.id" as that may be the spot I'm messing up.

I believe this problem has to do with something not accepting keyword arguments, but I struggle understanding Django's error messages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your url pattern has `<int:post_id>`, your function definition must accept `post_id`. Change it to:

```
def post(request, post_id):
```

Comment: The man, the myth, the legend. THANK YOU Alasdair you are truly a hero. Have a fantastic day this was exactly what I needed. <3

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add post_id to the post view

```
def post(request,post_id):
  """Show the text of a single blog post"""
  post=Post.objects.get(id=post_id)
  context = {'post':post}
  return render(request,'blogs/post.html',context)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try pass just pk in the urls param instead of post_id, something loke that

```
path('posts/<int:pk>/',views.post,name='post')
```

Comment: Doing this would change the message from `post() got an unexpected keyword argument 'post_id'` to `post() got an unexpected keyword argument 'pk'`, it wouldn't fix the error.